# DAX, Power BI, summarize table based on two columns

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure, multiple-conditions

Let's say that table looks like this :

| id | step | time |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 0.5 |
| 1 | a | 0.7 |
| 1 | b | 1 |
| 1 | b | 1.5 |
| 2 | a | 0.9 |
| 2 | a | 0.8 |

It's super simplified, but as you can see we can have the same ID and step more than once.

The question is **how to create a measure in PowerBI ( DAX) to summarize time under two or more conditions** without listing all steps and IDs  (for example for ID "1" step "a" occurs twice so my sum should be 1.2, step "b" 2.5 etc.)

Comment: Hi Kate, by this question I'm not sure you quite understand how a measure is used .... if you want the sum of the "time" values, then you just use SUM on that field.  The fact of whether you see an overall sum of ALL the records, or you see if for 1/a, 1/b, 2/a, etc. will come down to how you display or filter the data.  If you're displaying a table or chart, then "id" and "step" would be part of the rows or columns, or if you're including a filter on your report then the filter would be on either "id", "step" (or both).

Answer (score 2):

There is a nice function `SUMMARIZE`. You can create a table using this function:

```
Table 2 = SUMMARIZE(ALL('Table'), [id], [step], "time", SUM('Table'[time]))
```

[image]